# How can invoke gulp build from a Web Browser?

Tags: node.js, npm, gulp

Is there any possibility that I can invoke gulp tasks from the Web Browser ? I can create widgets for build ( Submit Button ) and that would invoke the corresponding gulp task?

Comment: Run a server that starts a `gulp` process when you hit it.

Comment: @ColonelThirtyTwo - u mean Java Servlet types which invokes a corresponding